# Removing groups with all NA in Data.Table or DPLYR in R

Tags: r, data.table

```
dataHAVE = data.frame("student"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5),
"time"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,3),
"score"=c(7,9,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,9,NA,NA,NA,7,NA,5))



dataWANT=data.frame("student"=c(1,1,1,3,3,3,5,5,5),
"time"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,NA,2,3),
"score"=c(7,9,5,NA,3,9,7,NA,5))
```

I have a tall dataframe and in that data frame I want to remove student IDS that contain NA for all 'score' or for all 'time'. This is just if it is all NA, if there are some NA then I want to keep all their records...

Comment: Hi bvowe. Are you looking for a `data.table` solution or why is that tag used?

Comment: @dario i was interested in data.table and dplyr because i am learning data.table and it is helpful to compare the solutions using both packages. thanks a bunch!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filter rows in data.table with \`by\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393053/filter-rows-in-data-table-with-by)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(dplyr)

dataHAVE %>%
    group_by(student) %>%
    filter(!all(is.na(score)))

  student  time score
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1     1     7
2       1     2     9
3       1     3     5
4       3     1    NA
5       3     2     3
6       3     3     9
7       5    NA     7
8       5     2    NA
9       5     3     5
```

Each `student` is only kept if not (`!`) `all` `score` values are `NA`

Comment: This misses the `time` constraint

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody suggested one, here is a solution using `data.table`:

```
  library(data.table)
  dataHAVE = data.table("student"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5),
                        "time"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,3),
                        "score"=c(7,9,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,9,NA,NA,NA,7,NA,5))
```

## Edit:

Previous but wrong code:

```
dataHAVE[, .SD[!(all(is.na(time)) & all(is.na(score)))], by = student]
```

New and correct code:

```
dataHAVE[, .SD[!(all(is.na(time)) | all(is.na(score)))], by = student]
```

Returns:

```
   student time score
1:       1    1     7
2:       1    2     9
3:       1    3     5
4:       3    1    NA
5:       3    2     3
6:       3    3     9
7:       5   NA     7
8:       5    2    NA
9:       5    3     5
```

## Edit:

Updatet `data.table` solution with @Cole s suggestion...

Comment: This is somewhat a duplicate question, but here's a decent looking way: ```dataHAVE[, .SD[!(all(is.na(time)) | all(is.na(score)))], by = student]``` See also: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/788

Comment: @Cole: Thanks a bunch for taking the time and looking up (and finding!) an excellent solution!

Comment: @this does not work. student 2 should be removed because all of their scores are NA

Comment: @bvowe: You are right of course. If fixed the missplaced `&` and replaced it with a correct `|`... sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `subset` + `ave`

```
dataWANT <- subset(dataHAVE,!(ave(time,student,FUN = function(v) all(is.na(v))) | ave(score,student,FUN = function(v) all(is.na(v)))))
```

or

```
dataWANT <- subset(dataHAVE,
                   !Reduce(`|`,Map(function(x) ave(get(x),student,FUN = function(v) all(is.na(v))), c("time","score"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataHAVE, key="student")
dataHAVE[!student %in% dataHAVE[, if(any(colSums(is.na(.SD))==.N)) student, student]$V1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy variable, and filter based on that

```r
library("dplyr")

dataHAVE = data.frame("student"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5),
                      "time"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,3),
                      "score"=c(7,9,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,9,NA,NA,NA,7,NA,5))

dataHAVE %>% 
  mutate(check=is.na(time)&is.na(score)) %>% 
  filter(check == FALSE) %>% 
  select(-check)
#>    student time score
#> 1        1    1     7
#> 2        1    2     9
#> 3        1    3     5
#> 4        2    1    NA
#> 5        2    2    NA
#> 6        2    3    NA
#> 7        3    1    NA
#> 8        3    2     3
#> 9        3    3     9
#> 10       5   NA     7
#> 11       5    2    NA
#> 12       5    3     5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` solution generalising to any number of columns:

```
dataHAVE[, 
         .SD[do.call("+", lapply(.SD, function(x) any(!is.na(x)))) == ncol(.SD)], 
         by = student]

#    student time score
# 1:       1    1     7
# 2:       1    2     9
# 3:       1    3     5
# 4:       3    1    NA
# 5:       3    2     3
# 6:       3    3     9
# 7:       5   NA     7
# 8:       5    2    NA
# 9:       5    3     5
```